# upload a file, on the backgroubd (html 5 workers)

Tags: c#, .net, html, file-upload, web-worker

i am building a WebApp and i am using .net with c#.

in this App the users have a function to upload files (specially images) to the server.
the file are not too big, its 400kb max.
the problem is that while the image is uploading they cant do anything, and have to wait untill its done (take something like 5 -30 seconds), but i want to upload the file on the background so in the time its uploading they will able to do other things.

i tried with html 5 workers, but its did not work.

some one have a idea how to do it?

thanks. Jordan..

Comment: How do you upload files with a file form or AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into **Asynchronous Pages**.

Here's a link to get you started:
[How to do an BackgroundWorker thread in ASP.NET?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1141831.aspx/1)

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking into Ajax Async File Upload inside a update panel which upload the file asynchronously.